# Using a Laravel Livewire and trying to display save button and cancel button on cell click

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a table that displays records that is pulled from LiveWire component. When I click on a specific cell, the Save, Cancel buttons and an input box appear. When I click back on the buttons, I want the buttons and the text disappear but for some stranger reason, they stay there and nothing changes. The cell does gets saved but buttons and an inputbox still show. This is my code in a products.blade.php

```
<table class="w-full text-sm text-left rtl:text-right dark:text-gray-400">
            <thead class="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">Qty</th>
                </tr>
            </head>
            <tbody>
            
            <?php $i = 0 ?>
            @foreach($products as $product)
            
            <tr wire:key="{{$product->id}}" wire:poll class="odd:bg-white hover:bg-gray-50 odd:dark:bg-gray-900 even:bg-gray-50 even:dark:bg-gray-800 border-b dark:border-gray-700">
                <td class="px-6 py-2 text-center" wire:click="editQty({{$product->id}})">
                    @if ($editProductID !== $product->id)
                        {{$product->p_qty}}
                    @else
                        <input type="text" wire:model.defer="productQty" class="bg-gray-100 test-gray-900 text-sm rounded block w-full p-2" />
                        <div class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                            <button type="button" wire:confirm="Are you sure?" wire:click="updateQty" class="text-blue-700 border border-blue-700 hover:bg-white-700 hover:text-white focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-full text-sm p-2 text-center inline-flex items-center dark:hover:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-800 dark:hover:bg-blue-500">
                           
                            <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" wire:click="cancelEdit" class="text-blue-700 border border-blue-700 hover:bg-white-700 hover:text-white focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-full text-sm p-2 text-center inline-flex items-center dark:border-blue-500 dark:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-800 dark:hover:bg-blue-500">
                                
                            <span class="sr-only">Cancel</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        @error("productQty")
                            {{$message}}
                        @enderror
                    @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr class="font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                    <th colspan="5" scope="row" class="px-6 py-3 text-base">Total</th>
                    <td colspan="3" class="px-6 py-3">${{number_format($totalCost,0)}}</td>
                    <td class="px-6 py-3">{{$totalQty}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

and on the component's side

```
public $editProductID = null;

#[Rule('required|min:1|max:3')]
public $productQty = null;

    public function updateQty() {
      $id = $this->editProductID;
      $this->validateOnly('productQty');

      Product::findOrFail($id)->update([
        'p_qty' => $this->productQty
         ]);

    $this->cancelEdit();
}

public function cancelEdit() {
    $this->reset('editProductID','productQty');
}

public function editQty($id) {
    $this->editProductID = $id;
    $this->productQty = Product::findOrFail($id)->p_qty;

}

public function render()
{
    $words = explode(' ', $this->search);
            
    foreach($words as $key => $word) {
        $words[$key] = 'keyword_build LIKE "%'.$word .'%" AND ';
    }
    $searchTerm = implode( ' ', $words);
    $searchTerm = substr($searchTerm,0,-5);
 
    if ($this->OnHand==1)
        $sign = ">=";
    else $sign = "<=";

    $products = Product::whereRaw($searchTerm)
        ->where('p_qty', $sign , $this->OnHand)
        ->orderBy($this->sortBy, $this->sortDirection);
        
    $totalQty = $products->sum('p_qty');
    $totalCost = $products->sum('p_price');

    $products = $products->paginate(perPage: 10);

    return view('livewire.products',["products"=>$products, 'totalCost' => $totalCost, 'totalQty' => $totalQty]);
}
```

As you can see, when I click on the cell, the buttons and the inputbox do appear and I click on cancel or save, nothing happens even though it does go to a function called cancelEdit() which do set values to null.

A help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: since you put the attribute ´´´wire:click=''editQty(...)´´´ on tr, you can expect any behavior from your livewire app, this attributes should be used only for buttons and anchors.

Comment: so how would you go about putting the table in the edit mode? I had an answer below to do a model:click.self credits to Pippo. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*wire:click* on the <td> element is activated also when you click on the elemets inside it, so the *edit-mode* is restarted also when you click *Cancel*.
To avoid this we can add the *self* modifier:

```html
<td class="px-6 py-2 text-center" wire:click.self="editQty({{$product->id}})">
```

in this way the clicks on the children elements are ignored

Also: with Livewire 3 wire:model is always deferred so you can safely remove *.defer* from *wire:model*

Comment: Thank you. It actually worked. I was breaking my head for 2 days.

Comment: Very well! If you want you can accept the answer and close the question